# Xamarin Archive error when generating apk

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

When I set Linking to None it works but when I set linking to Sdk and User Assemblies following error occurs

[image]

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/linking/

Comment: When I set Linking to None apk size is around 80 Mb

Comment: It is b/c all namespaces added with `using` statements are included in the build. The linker will determine and prune unreferenced assemblies.

Comment: By works do you mean it builds with a `using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml;` statement, or is it being used (instantiating classes, calling methods)?

Comment: The `System.IO.FileInfo` class has `Encrypt()` and `Decrypt()` members, though I haven't tried them. `var fInfo = new FileInfo(path); fInfo.Encrypt();`

Answer (score 2):

`Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0` is a desktop .NET assembly so it breaks your Xamarin.Android build. The same goes with `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml` which doesn't belong to the Xamarin.Android profile of Mono (as seen [here](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Security/common_System.Security.dll.sources))

[As explained by Brendan Zagaeski](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/76345/linkassemblies-task-failed-could-not-resolve-system-security-cryptography-xml-signedxml) from Xamarin, you'll need to find out how `Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0` is getting pulled in:

> - Are you explicitly referencing any .dll files from C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework that are outside of the MonoAndroid\ subfolder?
> - Are you explicitly including any 3rd-party libraries that might have been compiled against the desktop .NET profile?

You could post a screenshot of your References for the project, that could help narrow down the possibilities.